# Crop Bitmap with rectangle dimensions

Tags: android, bitmap, crop

I'm drawing a rectangle over a camera preview and i want to crop that specific region covered by the rectangle and display it in ImageView. I managed to crop the the Bitmap by using :

```
Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageOriginal, 50, 100, 1000, 550);
```

Code to draw the rectangle :

```
Rect rect = new Rect(50, 100,1000, 550);
```

as you can see i'm using the same parameters but i'm not getting the desired result. What i'm missing here ?. Thank you in advance.

**Camera Preview :**

[image]

**Cropped Bitmap displayed in new activity :**

[image]

Comment: Returns an immutable bitmap from the specified subset of the source bitmap. createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height).

where as 

Rect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
Create a new rectangle with the specified coordinates.

Comment: i've tried but i couldn't do it ! can you  pleaseexplain with an example ? also when the image is cropped i get a very zoomed bitmap ! how can i resolve this ? thank you in advance